# make php mail() send relevant domain name and not from default server hostname

Tags: linux, centos, php, sendmail, hostname

I'm not the sharpest server administrator in the draw, so i hope this isn't too much of a stupid question.

I'm looking to make php mail() send relevant domain name and not from default server hostname.

At the moment no matter what domain executes the task it is always stated as coming via my default server hostname.

i have have a Linux (CentOS 5.5) server with plesk installed and would assume the answer would either be in etc/hosts file or php.ini (sendmail_path) but now im stuck.

Thanks in advance.

TT

Comment: What parameters are you passing to the mail() function?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to pass "-fmy@fromaddress.com" as the fifth parameter to the `mail` function.

This does generate a warning on some mail servers that the From address has been changed and can sometimes be disallowed.

Alternatively, I'm quite happy using a library like `swiftmailer` these days which delivers to my local SMTP server directly and provides the ability to easily build more complex messages.